# New command changes the style of the text in math environment

Tags: math-mode, color

I'm trying to have this global command in my beamer document

```
\newcommand\x[1]{\color{myblue}{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

but when I use it the math style of the variables changes, any idea how to solve that

```
 \documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
 \definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\newcommand\x[1]{\color{myblue}{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\y[1]{\color{lava}{\mathbf{#1}}}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{}


\begin{itemize}
\item[]

$
\mathbf{E}_1\mathbf{A}=\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
\left[ \begin{array}{rrrr}
 a & b & c \\
d    &e &f  \\
g & h & i \\
\end{array}\right] = \left[ \begin{array}{rrrr}
 \x{a} & b & \x{c} \\
d    &e &f  \\
g & h & i \\
\end{array}\right]
$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify what "the math style of the variables changes" entails.

Comment: If you want the single argument to `\x` changes color, use `\textcolor{myblue}{\textbf{#1}}`. This is a duplicate of a recent question.

Comment: I've added a code to show what is the problem

Comment: That has nothing to do with color or newcommand, `\mathbf{a}` is always upright. Perhaps you should use `\bm{}` from the `bm` package instead.

Comment: I tried to use \bm, it didn't work as well

Comment: As Mico pointed out in his comment it would be greatly helpful if you could explain what "the math style of the variables changes" exactly mean: what do you _want_ to obtain?

Comment: Exactly what did you do with `\bm` (did you remembe to load the `bm` package)? I works just fine when I change your definitions for `\x` and `\y` to use `\bm` instread of `\mathbf`

Comment: it work, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although you could be more specific about what output you’re looking for, it seems that you want a bold italic math alphabet.

Either `unicode-math` (which requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX) or `isomath` (which is for PDFTeX) define a `\mathbfit` alphabet that you can use.  (`unicode-math` also defines a `\symbfit` command, which you might prefer.)

You can also use `\boldsymbol{\mathit{x}}`, from `amsmath`.  If you load `unicode-math` on a modern engine, or `bm` on an 8-bit one, it will use those packages’ improved bold glyphs.  It therefore is better to load `bm`, but use `\boldsymbol` rather than `\bm`.  You might want to use the same code with a different preamble later.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think you’re saying that `bm` has more-attractive glyphs than `amsbsy`? If so, I agree. In any case: `\boldsymbol` does correctly preserve the math class of its arguments, and it’s compatible with a much-wider selection of packages. If you load both packages, you get the same glyphs either way. So I recommend loading `bm` or `unicode-math` and writing `\boldsymbol`.